# Creating cell array matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have an output text file with 2 columns. One is time, the other consists of specific neuron numbers that are being spiked at each time interval.

I was wondering how I could make a cell array matrix where it shows the neuron numbers on the y axis, and time on the x axis from my output file? Where there is a vertical line for each recurrence of a specific neuron spiking at a specific time?

So far I know how to plot an x,y graph, but am unable to make vertical lines appear where a neuron number spikes.

Comment: Plotting a cell array matrix doesn't make much sense.  A cell array is a MATLAB data type: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html.  Can you provide us with what this text file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, some information and/or code snippets would be neccesary to help you further.

-Your file should be either a `.mat` or `.csv`. The first can be imported into the workspace with the command `load('my_file.mat')`, the second with `M = csvread(filename)`.

-As @rayreng commented, there is no real use in this case for cell arrays (as far as I see, again, you should provide more info for a proper answer).

-Not sure what you mean with vertical lines, but of course you could use `stem` for a discrete plot of your neurons.

Comment: orry about that! So far i have a textfile from the program 'Neuron'. Which has two columns: 
ex.  Column 1 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003    
     Column 2  244      595     244
    (But columns)
Where Column 1 is time, and Column 2 is the Neuron ID#. So, at 0.0001 seconds neuron 244 was spiked. I'm hoping to create a plot where it will have time on the x-axis, then neuron # on y-axis, where there will appear a line on the plot at each time where that neuron is spiked, for each neuron#.  So far in matlab i've written:
fid= fopen('out.dat','r')
C = textscan(fid, '%f %d')
t=c(:,1)
cellid=c(:,2)

Comment: As I said, and with what you have explaned,`stem(x,y)` should get it done.